# Where can I find core Bluetooth specifications?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to leverage bluetooth (GATT, GAP, Security Manager, Pairing, Broadcast etc...) using BlueZ.

To decode BlueZ however I need access to full bluetooth core/protocol specifications. As an individual developer, where can I get hold of these specifications?

The membership to Bluetooth SIG requires me to be part of an incorporated company and I am asked to send them filing details etc...

Is there a way to get hold of Bluetooth Core Specs for individuals and hobby developers?

Importantly does BlueZ fully implement all Bluetooth Core specifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bluetooth specification should be free to download for everyone. You can find the latest specification at the following link:-

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/

Make sure to click at the "5.1" link.

BlueZ is fully compliant with the Bluetooth specification, however, it does not support all the available features in the specification.

I hope this helps.